# Multi-table join in EF

Tags: entity-framework

In SQL Server I have this query:

```
SELECT cvs.* 
  FROM dbo.ClientVoiceSetup cvs
 WHERE cvs.EnrollmentCode = 74311
/** Apply Vendor Data Scope **/
   AND cvs.ClientID IN (
SELECT DISTINCT cc.client_id
  FROM cli_case cc
 INNER JOIN cli_case_plan     ccp ON  cc.case_id         = ccp.case_id
 INNER JOIN service_plan       sp ON ccp.service_plan_id =  sp.service_plan_id
 INNER JOIN VendorServicePlan vsp ON  sp.service_plan_id = vsp.ServicePlanID
/** Apply Vendor ID from login **/
 WHERE vsp.VendorID = 4)
```

NOTES:  In SQL, client <--> cli_case <--> cli_case_plan do not have any FKs defined.  service_plan <--> VendorServicePlan <--> Vendor *do* have FKs defined where VendorServicePlan is a many-to-many join table only.

The sub-query is a data scoping filter that will be applied to multiple different calls.  When I dragged the DB into EF I ended up with a slightly different structure.  I have the following entities:

client
cli_case
cli_case_plan
service_plan (with a Vendors ICollection)
Vendor (with a service_plan ICollection)

I've created the following JOIN in code:

```
var q = (from cc in context.cli_case
    join ccp in context.cli_case_plan on cc.case_id equals ccp.case_id
    join sp in context.service_plan on ccp.service_plan_id equals sp.service_plan_id
    select cc.client_id);
return q.ToList();
```

I'm drawing a blank on how to add the "WHERE clause" for VendorID == myInput.

As a side note:  I would love to figure out how to return the unmaterialized EF statement rather than the results from a DB call.  The long term idea is to inject this statement as a filter to a "normal" EF call so when it is materialized it includes the filtering.  (Why call the DB twice when you can call it once?)  Unless there is a better approach?

Comment: And where is the last join?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out...

Comment: `where sp.Vendors.Contains(inputVendorId)`?

Comment: Figured it out:  where sp.Vendors.Any(a => a.VendorID == vendorId)  - will add to my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

**LINQ for SQL**

```
var p = (from cc in context.cli_case
         join ccp in context.cli_case_plan on cc.case_id equals ccp.case_id
         join sp in context.service_plan on ccp.service_plan_id equals sp.service_plan_id
         where sp.Vendors.Any(a => a.VendorID == vendorId)
         select cc.client_id);
```

**LINQ for Objects**

```
    var q = context.cli_case.Join(context.cli_case_plan, cc => cc.case_id, ccp => ccp.case_id, (cc, ccp) => new {cc, ccp})
        .Join(context.service_plan, @t => @t.ccp.service_plan_id, sp => sp.service_plan_id, (@t, sp) => new {@t, sp})
        .Where(ven => ven.sp.Vendors.Any(a => a.VendorID == vendorId))
        .Select(a => a.@t.cc.client_id);
```

I can then return this as an IQuerayble< int > and use it further up the line:

```
var enrollmentCode = 13524;
// provides the underlying SQL, does not hit the DB...
var clientList = db.GetClientIdListFromVendorId(4);
// set WHERE clause to filter on enrollmentCode and allowed client list...
var q = db.ClientSetups
          .Where(a => a.EnrollmentCode == enrollmentCode
                   && clientList.Contains(a.ClientID))
          .ToList();
```